# Show required OAuth scopes on each endpoint in swagger for .net core

Tags: .net-core, swagger

The API I am documenting has a lot of scopes available. Currently getting all scopes the API has However wants to display each endpoint is providing what scopes authorize for it.

Something link below:
[image]

Comment: [This appears to be the documentation section](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) relevant to emitting security definitions in Swashbuckle for .net, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: so all the links including above is for showing all scopes together however I wants to display each endpoint is providing what scopes authorize for it.